# React state returning NULL on submit, despite logging non-NULL value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-state-management

The intended functionality is as follows:

1. Select an item in the list by pressing (calls `onPressSport()`)
2. The item's value is stored in the `sport` state
3. When the next button is pressed, `onPressNext()` is called (which calls a function from context)

The problem occurs in Step 3 when I log the value of `sport`. Before `onPressNext()` is called, the value is logged as a non-NULL value; however, the log within `onPressNext()` is always `null`.

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Pressable,
  TextInput,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native'
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import userContext from '../../context/user/userContext'
import gameContext from '../../context/game/gameContext'
import { SPORTS } from '../../sample_data'
import { doHaptics } from '../../functions'
import ErrorAlert from '../../ErrorAlert'

const CreateGame_Sport = ({navigation, route}) => {
  const {game, new_selectSport} = useContext(gameContext)
  // const {sport} = game

  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
  const [results, setResults] = useState([])
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [sport, setSport] = useState(game?.sport || null)

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: 'Pick a sport',
      headerLeft: () => (
        <Pressable style={hStyles.backButton} onPress={onPressBack} hitSlop={16}>
          <Feather name="chevron-left" size={28} color="#212121"/>
        </Pressable>
      ),
      headerRight: () => (
        <Pressable style={hStyles.nextButton} onPress={onPressNext} hitSlop={16}>
          <Text style={hStyles.nextButtonText}>Next</Text>
        </Pressable>
      ),
    })
  }, [navigation])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!search)
      return setResults([])
    const filtered = SPORTS.filter(({name}) => name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
    setResults(filtered)
  }, [search])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Sport updated!')
    console.log(sport)
  }, [sport])

  const onPressBack = () => navigation.pop()

  const onPressClear = () => {
    setSearch('')
    setResults([])
  }

  const onPressSport = (val) => setSport(val)

  const onPressNext = async () => {
    console.log('sport: ', sport)
    if (!sport) {
      await doHaptics('medium')
      return setError('Please select a sport!')
    }
    new_selectSport(sport)
    return navigation.push('CreateGame_Type')
  }

  const onEndReached = async () => {}

  const renderItem = ({item}, index) => {
    const {_id, name, icon: Icon} = item
    const selected = sport?._id === _id
    return (
      <Pressable style={selected ? styles.resultAdded : styles.result} onPress={() => onPressSport(item)}
                 key={_id}>
        <View style={styles.resultColumn}>
          <Text style={styles.resultName}>{name}</Text>
        </View>
        <Icon style={styles.resultIcon}/>
      </Pressable>
    )
  }

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} verticalOffset={64}>
      <ErrorAlert error={error} setError={setError}/>
      <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
        <Feather name="search" size={18} color="#808080" style={styles.searchIcon}/>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.searchInput}
          value={search}
          defaultValue={search}
          onChangeText={value => setSearch(value)}
          placeholder="Search by name..."
          placeholderTextColor="#808080"
          returnKeyType="default"
          spellCheck={true}
        />
        {search ? (
          <Pressable style={styles.searchClearButton} onPress={onPressClear}>
            <Feather name="x" size={12} color="#eee"/>
          </Pressable>
        ) : null}
      </View>
      {search ? results ? (
        <FlatList
          data={results}
          extraData={sport}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
          initialNumToRender={16}
          onEndReached={onEndReached}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContainer}
        />
      ) : null : (
        <FlatList
          data={SPORTS}
          extraData={sport}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          initialNumToRender={16}
          onEndReached={onEndReached}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContainer}
        />
      )}
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )
}

export default CreateGame_Sport
```

Any and all suggestions are welcome! :)